# Inicialização Automática de Programas

Tags: bat, inicialização

Bom, tenho dois programas um escrito em **JAVA** que consulta um banco de dados e e gera um xml, e outro escrito em **C++** que percorre o xml gerado pelo programa em java. Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de criar um serviço ou algo do tipo para que eles sejam executados em um determinado período, por serão instalados em uma maquina como servidor. Eu pensei em algo do tipo criar um .bat para rodar os dois e depois se for possível transformar esse bat em um serviço. Como sou iniciante gostaria de sugestões.

Comment: Use o "agendador de Tarefas" do windows.

Comment: Se estiver no linux, você pode usar o cron